# Will I have to pay several thousand dollars for a premium domain every year?

Tags: domains

I want to buy `coolandexpensivedomain.com` domain that costs a couple of thousand dollars.

When the domain is transferred to me, will I have to pay that amount **again** when I have to renew it? Or the usual price of *10-something* dollars?

Comment: That is the price one time only. However, I would recommend that you do not reward bad behavior. These domain squaters are the scum of the internet falling far below spammers and hackers. Keep your money in your pants and just find a domain name that works without being hijacked by the squaters B.S. You can find an acceptable name easy enough. You just have to think about it for a while. Do not burn capital without a return on investment (ROI) before you even begin. That would be foolish.

Comment: post that as an answer closenotc.

Comment: Sadly as much as I hate domain squatters there is a huge demand for short domains in the `.com` range. Branding is important and if you have the budget then yes, you should buy the more remember-able brand-able domain names.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will not have to pay several thousand of dollars or the same amount that you bought the ownership when you renew this Domain name.

**After you transfer** the Domain to your preferred Registrar and **take full ownership**, you only pay the Domain renewal price that is defined by your Registrar and nothing more.

After Domain transfer is completed, activate "Domain Locking (Registrar Lock)" just in any case.

---

From http://icannwiki.com/Domain_Locking :

> Domain Locking, sometimes referred to as Registry or
>   Registrar-locking, describes the service provided by registries or
>   registrars to "lock" a domain name so that it cannot be transferred or
>   altered without the explicit permission of the registrant.
>
> If a lock is in place, the registrant must request that the name be
>   "unlocked" before such changes can be made.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registrar-Lock :

> REGISTRAR-LOCK is a status code that can be set on an Internet domain
>   name by the sponsoring registrar of the domain name.
>
> This is usually done in order to prevent unauthorized, unwanted or accidental
>   changes to the domain name.

Comment: Answer is updated